# how to solve No Such Method Error

Tags: java, nosuchmethoderror

I am working on swing application in netbeans. I have created one parent class and a child class. Whenever I am calling any attribute of parent class through child class I am getting error. How to solve this:

this is parent class:

```
public abstract class WorkRequest {

private String name;
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}}
```

this is child class:

```
public class DoctorTestWorkRequest extends WorkRequest {

private String message;

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}
```

I am calling child class in a panel:

```
DoctorTestWorkRequest request = new DoctorTestWorkRequest();
    request.setName(name);
    request.setMessage(message);
```

I am getting an exception that:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: Business.WorkQueue.DoctorTestWorkRequest.setName(Ljava/lang/String;)V
at UserInterface.ReceptionistRole.DoctorTestWorkRequestJPanel.requestTestJButtonActionPerformed(DoctorTestWorkRequestJPanel.java:147)
```

How to solve this. thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe you have an old version of the class in your classpath. clean your project and recompile it

Comment: The following error occurred while executing this line:
SmartHealthCareSystem\nbproject\build-impl.xml:263: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Comment: What's the compiler output? Could you [edit] your question to mention that?

Comment: This is just speculative, but `name` is `private`. Private variables are _not_ accessible to subclasses. I'm not sure how this affects methods that affect private variables, but can you try changing `name` to `public` or `protected` and tell us what happens?

Comment: Note that if the compiler fails you might still have old classes on your classpath which can cause that problem.

Comment: Still I am facing the same error.

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be in the IDE cache, so to be sure to solve this rename the WorkRequest class to WorkRequestNew and use the new name in the

`public class DoctorTestWorkRequest extends WorkRequestNew`

hope this will help.

Comment: Yes that worked. Thank you so much. Why it took place? Can you explain me!!

Comment: yes, this problem is commun in inner classes, your .class must be Business$WorkQueue$DoctorTestWorkRequest$WorkRequest.class (you can see her the NetBeans issue : https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=247819)

Answer (score -3):

create an instance of WorkRequest and then initialize it to DoctorTestWorkRequest

`WorkRequest request = new DoctorTestWorkRequest;`

this should work

Comment: How would that be better than `DoctorTestWorkRequest request = new DoctorTestWorkRequest();` (from a code point of view, not talking about design)?

Comment: But by doing this I will not be able to access the message attribute in child class.

Comment: `new DoctorTestWorkRequest;` is not legal Java.